# How does Fancybox for Wordpress got hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, fancybox

[Fancybox for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) widely got hacked by ISIS. Even with latest version at this moment installed (v3.0.6), my WordPress site (v3.9.2) is still printing out the ISIS statement. The method to cure the issue is to disable / remove the plugin.

Hacker inserts code via non-sanitized Fancybox option to "insert" codes to the site.

However, I'm curious how can the hackers perform this kind of attack (e.g. how do they target my website? do they need to send attacks non-stop to our server? *my server is very slow by the way*)? and how to prevent these attacks in our development?

For more details of the attack, please read [this article](http://blog.sucuri.net/2015/02/zero-day-in-the-fancybox-for-wordpress-plugin.html).

Comment: The link you posted has a link a [second article explaining how the attack works](http://blog.sucuri.net/2015/02/analysis-of-the-fancybox-for-wordpress-vulnerability.html), which answers some of your questions around the how

Comment: Yes, I read that, but is the attack on-going after I remove Fancybox (how do I know?) ? and is there anything I can stop them from attacking ? How do they pick my website instead of other site ?

Comment: It's easy enough to do a Google search to find sites that use a given plugin. I'd guess they attacked as many of those sites as possible, and you were just unlucky. I suspect (but I _really_ can't be certain) that once you remove the plugin, the values the hackers inserted into the options table won't appear on your site, so you should be safe. The article you linked to advocated removing it, but didn't mention any other clean-up.  I guess you could remove the options from your table manually if the uninstall doesn't do it for you, just to be safe, but I doubt other code would use the values

Comment: I completely removed the related codes, but the attacks still going on (receiving non-stop malware injection requests), making the server very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I consider this question "off-topic" I will add my five cents here :

> How does Fancybox for Wordpress got hacked?

First, bear in mind that **this is not a FancyBox issue** but a PHP vulnerability. Any WP plugin is coded in PHP, and poor PHP code is prone to vulnerabilities, flaws and attacks.

Second, the WP plugin's author may not be the same as the original jQuery plugin (it is not in this case or any other I am aware of) so even though the original jQuery plugin can be robust and stable, it can be poorly implemented by others in WP.

> how do they target my website?

They didn't target your website because is your website. Most attacks are performed by robots that crawl the net in search of back-doors and vulnerabilities found in poor code. It was most likely a random attack and you were just the unlucky guy in the path of the robot's crawl.

> how to fix it?

Removing a compromised WP plugin may not solve or stop the issue because the attack may not come from that plugin any more.

Some attacks may spread and inject other files (through the back door in the vulnerable plugin) into your WP directory structure. You may need to browse your directories (via FTP) and remove/rename any suspicious file (most likely PHP files) that were created/modified on and after the date of the first "attack".

You may need to revoke their permissions too.

> how to prevent these attacks in our development?

Choose a robust (well documented and updated) plugin and update your WP version too.

Despite I shouldn't endorse any third-party software or plugin, a more stable and robust FancyBox WP plugin for your WP site would be [EasyFancybox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/).

The best option IMHO (not necessarily the most user-friendly) is not using a plugin at all, and hard-code the original FancyBox js and css files (as well as your FancyBox initialization script) yourself in the *header.php* file of your WP theme.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. Really appreciated.

Comment: I find this answer too general and doesn't reflect the actual issue / deface that the user described and linked.

Comment: @jnhghy-JanteaAlexandru : the question is "off-topic" so does the answer, however the points I state in this (more an opinion than an) answer actually explain what the OP requested, hence it was accepted. We can agree to disagree though ;)